# How to make Image Slider with using gallery images in android

Tags: android, slider

Im trying to do image slider with gallery images.I can get image from gallery but I could not to display like a slideshow , Could you help me about that how can I do that.

Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE = 1;
    String imageEncoded;
    List<String> imagesEncodedList;
    public static final int IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST = 20;
    private ImageView imgPicture;

    InputStream inputstream;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imgPicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE);}

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        try {
            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                // Get the Image from data

                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                imagesEncodedList = new ArrayList<String>();
                if(data.getData()!=null){

                    Uri mImageUri=data.getData();

                    // Get the cursor
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(mImageUri,
                            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    // Move to first row
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    imageEncoded  = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    display(null,mImageUri,true);
                    cursor.close();

                } else {
                    if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                        ClipData mClipData = data.getClipData();
                        ArrayList<Uri> mArrayUri = new ArrayList<Uri>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < mClipData.getItemCount(); i++) {

                            ClipData.Item item = mClipData.getItemAt(i);
                            Uri uri = item.getUri();
                            mArrayUri.add(uri);
                            // Get the cursor
                            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                            // Move to first row
                            cursor.moveToFirst();

                            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);

                            imageEncoded  = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                            imagesEncodedList.add(imageEncoded);
                            cursor.close();
                            display(mArrayUri,null,false);

                        }
                        Log.v("LOG_TAG", "Selected Images" + mArrayUri.size());
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    public void display(ArrayList<Uri> list, Uri SUri, Boolean x)
    {

        if(x){
            // declare a stream to read the image data from the SD Card.
            InputStream inputStream;

            // we are getting an input stream, based on the URI of the image.
            try {
                inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(SUri);

                // get a bitmap from the stream.
                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);


                // show the image to the user
                imgPicture.setImageBitmap(image);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                // show a message to the user indictating that the image is unavailable.
                Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to open image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }else
        {
            InputStream inputStream;

            // we are getting an input stream, based on the URI of the image.

            for (int i= 0; i<list.size(); i++) {
                try {
                    inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(list.get(i));

                    // get a bitmap from the stream.
                    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);


                    // show the image to the user
                    imgPicture.setImageBitmap(image);

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    // show a message to the user indictating that the image is unavailable.
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to open image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }



    }


}
```

Comment: you can use view pager to display images like slide show

Comment: yes I know that but I could not put my image to viewpager

Comment: get all your images  path or Uri in array list and send this array list to view pager adapter and display it into image view

Comment: GalleryView is deprecated now. The alternatives include HorizontalScrollView and ViewPager from the support library. The best alternative way is to use ViewPager with an ImageView in its fragment layout. you can check it here https://www.androidhive.info/2016/04/android-glide-image-library-building-image-gallery-app/

Comment: guys Im really confused rightnow , Nilesh Rathod can you help me how can do your way.

Comment: I have problem viewpager İs there anyone to help me about that .Coud you send me code about that how can I put my images to viewpager